# what is aspectj-maven-plugin used for

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I am unable to understand why this plugin is used for. Working on changeing a multi module project to single module. The plugin was being used in the multi module. This is how it was used in the pom :

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <!-- use this goal to weave main classes -->
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <!-- use this goal to weave test classes -->
                        <!-- <goal>test-compile</goal> -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) is a wrapper around Eclipse' [AspectJ Project](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/). A common example: it gives you the opportunity the prepend or append codefragments to a methodcall, like adding some logging to every method call. (instead of manually adding it to *every* method in the sourcefiles)

Comment: thanks @Robert...for the time I have decided to leave the plugin as it is in the pom